# Write a filtered wordcount function with Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter, rdd

```
text_file = sc.textFile("data.txt")
counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
             .filter(lambda word: re.sub(r"\p{P}+", word) in word) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
print(counts.collect())
```

I have a word count code like this, and want to filter out the punctuation but when I add the **filter()** function, it gets error when running **collect()** function.
Without the filter() everything is ok but list of word will contain some words like [('primaries.', 1), ('1946)', 1), ('let's', 2)...] and not so clean :(